# Multiple Language Support

Tags: android, cordova, internationalization, i18n-gem

Android Mobile Application  that Support To Multiple Languages

What Is the best way

Either Use different different values folder for Hindi , French etc

Or

Languages Translator like in Web Projects

Or

Any other...way

Please Suggest me the best way.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Have a look at Java resource bundles.  There's a lot of material on Google if you type in "java i18n"

Answer (score 3):

For Native Android project you could create a public interface that extends from constants, for example TitlesConstants.java:

```
  public interface TitlesConstants extends Constants{

     @DefaultStringValue("Login") String login();
     @DefaultStringValue("Logout") String logout();
  }
```

Then create property file, for example TitlesConstants_eu.properties(Basque Language):

```
  login=Sartu
  logout=Irten
```

The last thing it's to call you're interface from your Java code and get the translation depending the locale you're using to view your data.

This way it's doing it all by yourself.